# Ruby (Rails): remove whitespace from each array item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

[I found this code](http://granth.ca/2006/02/strip-whitespace):

```
.each_key {|a| self[a].strip! if self[a].respond_to? :strip! }
```

...but it is for a hash, whereas I am trying to do the same with an array.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is what `collect` is for.

The following handles `nil` elements by leaving them alone:

```
yourArray.collect{ |e| e ? e.strip : e }
```

If there are *no `nil` elements*, you may use:

```
yourArray.collect(&:strip)
```

...which is short for:

```
yourArray.collect { |e| e.strip }
```

`strip!` behaves similarly, but it converts *already "stripped" strings* to `nil`:

```
[' a', ' b ', 'c ', 'd'].collect(&:strip!)
=> ["a", "b", "c", nil]
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-collect

https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip

Comment: I am really new to Ruby, but isn't `.strip` should never return `nil`. `.strip!` though returns `nil` if it didn't strip anything. I can confirm that with interactive shell (irb).

Comment: Can you explain why you did the `|| x`?

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind first **removing `nil` elements**:

```
YourArray.compact.collect(&:strip)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-compact

Comment: FYI you don't want to call `compact` on `Array` itself.  For your answer supply something like `a.compact.collect(&:strip)` or use `yourArray` as in Jamie's answer.  I know you are going for pseudocode but it is helpful to the questioner to be technically precise.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Rails, consider [squish](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish):

> Returns the string, first removing all whitespace on both ends of the string, and then changing remaining consecutive whitespace groups into one space each.

```
yourArray.collect(&:squish)
```

Comment: Just to shorten it a bit. `myArray.collect(&:squish)`

Answer (score 3):

Adapting the approach you found, from working on a hash to working on an array:

```
[' c ', 'd', nil, 6, false].each { |a| a.strip! if a.respond_to? :strip! }
=> ["c", "d", nil, 6, false]
```

Comment: I am doing row.each {|a| a.strip! if a.respond_to? :strip! } (and have tried row2 = row.each {|a| a.strip! if a.respond_to? :strip! } to make sure it wasn't that , but the items still have the white space.  Not sure it helps, but I am doing this on a csv file that I am pulling in with FasterCSV.  I could probably clean up the CSV output, but would be useful to know this for the future anyways.

Comment: @Toby (to updated comment) Check which type array elements have (e.g., `puts x[0].class`). If it's not a string, you can't use string's `strip!` method on them.

Comment: turns out I am just dumb, I didn't know that if you use :headers => true, it would make each item an array with the header as the first element, and the value as the second, I got it to work on the second item, then found out it was just as easy to add -W to sqlcmd to output from mssql without the whitespace.  Thanks for everyone's help.